# Im trying to make tetris in Basic , but I have encoutered a problem which i cant seem to solve

Tags: basic, dosbox, qbasic, gw-basic

```
' Define the subroutine
SUB MySubroutine
    PRINT "Hello, world!"
END SUB

' Call the subroutine
CALL MySubroutine
```

I wanted to try and make TetrisTetris in qbasic but I'm trying to figure out subs in QBasic and for some reason, there's an error that states "statements cannot be placed between subs/functions" (on line 6 for the code above). I have clearly ended the sub as seen in line 4 . how can I fix this, **I have tried many different versions of qbasic and different compilers for qbasic and still I get the same issue** ***yes I tried reinstalling qbasic***

If you wonder why im using basic in the first place its because i saw a movie where a guy made tetris in qbasic ( he dint have a video card and used [] insted of graphics )

Comment: You don't actually need the `CALL` keyword here. Just `MySubroutine` (at the right place) is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QBasic you edit your SUB's and FUNCTION's each in their separate windows. In such an edit window, the `END SUB` or `END FUNCTION` statement is supposed to be the last statement. Nothing should follow it.

> ```
> ' Define the subroutine
> SUB MySubroutine
>     PRINT "Hello, world!"
> END SUB
> ```

From such an edit window, you need to return to the main module (using <kbd>F2</kbd> and selecting the program's name pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and place your `CALL MySubroutine` statement there, along with all the rest that isn't either a SUB or a FUNCTION.

Comment: thank you, it seems to work now I just got confused as to how a sub can be called before it is defined .

Comment: @Mirazz_Boi If its not defined before the call it needs to be at least declared.  QBasic does this automatically for you.  When you save the file, DECLARE statements are inserted at the top of the file.